# r not encoding correctly special characters

Tags: r

I am importing data from a firebird bd using dbConnect() and dbGetQuery() but when I check data, special characters like Ç,Â,Á... are not showing in the R console. Those are special characters used in portuguese language.

I tried

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Portuguese_Brazil.1252")
```

But it doesn´t work

I also tried

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),"repro",encoding = "UTF-8")
dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT * FROM .....
```

But no success

Trying to use directly the special characters it does work so I believe the Sys.setlocale it is working in this case but not when importing data. Example:

```
 A <- c("Ç","Â","Á")
    A
[1] "Ç" "Â" "Á"
```

Is there a way I can fix this ?

Appreciate any help

Comment: LC_TIME affects time, not encoding.  Try LC_ALL.

Comment: hi, I edited the question, I am using  LC_ALL in fact.

Comment: What encoding is the database using?  Portuguese_Brazil.1252 and UTF-8 are completely different.